# Adding videos to MiniDLNA Raspberry using LAN

Tags: video, home-networking, streaming, raspberry-pi, dlna

I have a Raspberry with MiniDLNA, it acts as a dlna server through my local network.
I have connected an external HDD to the Raspberry, which contains all my videos.
Everything works well, without problems, there's only one thing I'd like to do...

When I have to add a video to the HDD, I have to remove the wire from my Raspberry, plug it in the PC, copy the video and then back into the Rasp. It's not a hard job, but I was asking myself: is there a way to add a video to the HDD ONLY USING my local network, via Ethernet?

I have installed Webmin on my Raspberry which lets me control a lot of functions of MiniDLNA, but I haven't found any option to add videos directly without moving cables.
Is there a module to do so? If not, how should I do?

Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

I would install samba and set up a share linked to the same directory as your minidlna library. This will allow you to access the folder over your network. This guide should help you with that: [samba set up guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)

Comment: I have found that Webmin has the option to upload files to the Raspberry via LAN, but it's extremely low... Around 5 minutes for a 25MB file. Do you think the shared samba folder would be faster? I actually can't understand why it's so low!

Comment: It's hard to say, I'm not familiar with webmin's upload feature. I'd suggest that it's worth a try since that is far too slow.